# Serializar Objeto para JSON

Tags: json, python

Como faço para converter um objeto em JSON?

Até achei alguns códigos na internet que até funcionou, porém meu objeto possui alguns campos que são outros objetos e então a conversão não chegou até o último nível.

Exemplo:

```
class Pessoa(object):
    codigo = 0
    nome = ''
    endereco = Endereco()

class Endereco(object):
    codigo = 0
    logradouro = ''
    bairro = ''
    cidade = Cidade()

class Cidade(object):
    codigo = 0
    nome = ''
    uf = ''
```

Esses são meus objetos, porém fazendo a conversão que encontrei, o resultado JSON vem apenas com os valores contidos em **Pessoa** em **Endereco**, ficando então **Cidade** de fora do JSON:

```
{
    'codigo': 1,
    'nome': 'Oliveira',
    'endereco': {
        'codigo': 5,
        'logradouro': 'Rua A',
        'bairro': 'Campos'            
    }
}
```

Ou seja, acredito que o código não percorreu todos os níveis.

Estou usando o **pyMongo** e vi que possui uma biblioteca **bson** que possui algumas conversões, mas eu não soube usa-la ou então ela não faz o que eu preciso.

Comment: Eu estou meio confuso - o que são esses campos definidos na classe? Você sabe que quando define campos desse jeito, eles são estáticos, certo? Pra definir campos de objetos, você faz dentro do `__init__`. Talvez seja por isso que os métodos de conversão objeto/json que você experimentou não estejam dando o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então cara, em **Python** existe o tipo de dado `Dictionary` que é tipo o `Map` de outras linguagens, é uma estrutura de `(key, value)`, ou seja, quase parecido com o problema que você está precisando, porque o formato **Json** segue esse padrão de (key, value). 
Segue um exemplo abaixo de um uso dessa estrutura que já vem na linguagem e não precisa de outros pacotes e módulos, porém você deve adaptar ao seu uso aí, obviamente:

```
Pessoa = {}
Endereco = {}
Cidade = {}

Endereco['Logradouro'] = "Rua A"
Endereco['Numero'] = 80
Endereco['Bairro'] = "Centro"

Cidade['Nome'] = "Belo Horizonte"
Cidade['UF'] = "Minas Gerais"
Cidade['Codigo'] = 0

Pessoa['Nome'] = "Meu nome é esse"
Pessoa['Codigo'] = 1
Pessoa['Endereco'] = Endereco
Pessoa['Cidade'] = Cidade

print(repr(Pessoa))
```

**Resultado**

```
{
    "Nome": "Meu nome é esse",
    "Codigo": 1,
    "Endereco": {
        "Numero": 80,
        "Logradouro": "Rua A",
        "Bairro": "Centro"
     },
    "Cidade": {
        "Nome": "Belo Horizonte",
        "Codigo": 0,
        "UF": "Minas Gerais"
     }
}
```

Então você pode fazer uma classe que monta esses dicionários separadamente, utilizando os métodos de acesso aos seus objetos, e, com o método `repr(obj)` que já te retorna o **json** que você precisa, está resolvido seu problema.

Comment: Tem certeza que o resultado de `repr` é sempre json válido? Se você já tem uma estrutura só com `dict`s, `list`s e primitivos, pode usar `import json` e `s = json.dumps(obj)` pra produzir um json válido - e sem o risco de serializar coisas que não são válidas, como funções. Como o módulo `json` é nativo do Python, não precisa de bibliotecas externas.

Comment: Um contra-exemplo: `>>> repr({'teste com aspas':'"'})` saída: `'{\'teste com aspas\': \'"\'}'`. Usando `json.dumps`: `'{"teste com aspas": "\\""}'`

Comment: Mas nesses casos seus, você já está jogando uma ``str`` para o método ``repr`` e não um ``dict`` como sugerido para ele ir montando. A questão é que, pelo que vi por aí, a estrutura ``dict`` implementa um método default para todos objetos que é o ``obj.__repr__()``, que aí quando eu chamo o ``repr(obj)`` internamente é chamado esse método, que pega os pares ``(key, value)`` e reproduz eles do tipo ``json``. No seu caso apresentado são ``str``'s e aí a reprodução é diferente mesmo. Porém, a forma que apresentei é apenas uma das formas, utilizando o módulo ``json`` também é uma boa.

Comment: Eu passei um `dict` pro `repr`, não uma string. De todo modo, pra usar esse método a pessoa tem que tomar cuidado pro objeto não ter funções, tuplas, datas... Não estou dizendo que não dá pra usar, só acho o `json` mais seguro/robusto.

Comment: Bom, nisso eu concordo!

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda cara, ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 5):

Em primeiro lugar, você precisa definir os seus campos dentro do `__init__`, e não assim na classe, pois do contrário eles serão compartilhados por todas as instâncias da classe (i.e. serão "estáticos") em vez de ter um para cada objeto:

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.codigo = 0
        self.nome = ''
        self.endereco = Endereco()

class Endereco(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.codigo = 0
        self.logradouro = ''
        self.bairro = ''
        self.cidade = Cidade()

class Cidade(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.codigo = 0
        self.nome = ''
        self.uf = ''
```

(pode colocar parâmetros - opcionais ou obrigatórios - no construtor se quiser, em vez de iniciar tudo com um valor padrão; só tome cuidado com os valores padrão que também são objetos, colocá-lo na assinatura do método trará efeitos indesejados)

Muitas vezes você não *precisa* de classes - usar literais para `dict`, ou criá-los à mão mesmo (como [sugerido por Christian Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139717/215)) pode ser suficiente. Entretanto, as classes podem ser úteis se você pretende lhes dar métodos, então não digo para não usar, use sim se for necessário/conveniente.

Feito isso, as bibliotecas de conversão objeto/json que você experimentou devem dar o resultado correto. Mas caso queira um método simples de fazer à mão, você pode se aproveitar do fato que o campo `__dict__` de um objeto transforma suas propriedades em campos de um `dict`:

```
import json

def para_dict(obj):
    # Se for um objeto, transforma num dict
    if hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        obj = obj.__dict__

    # Se for um dict, lê chaves e valores; converte valores
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return { k:para_dict(v) for k,v in obj.items() }
    # Se for uma lista ou tupla, lê elementos; também converte
    elif isinstance(obj, list) or isinstance(obj, tuple):
        return [para_dict(e) for e in obj]
    # Se for qualquer outra coisa, usa sem conversão
    else: 
        return obj

p = Pessoa()
s = json.dumps(para_dict(p))
```

Isso deve funcionar para os casos mais comuns, e o uso do `json.dumps` garante que ao menos nada inválido será ecoado para a saída.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda cara, ajudou bastante!