# Serializar Python objects em JSON

Tags: python, json

Alguém sabe como serializar em YAML ou JSON uma classe que contém atributos que contém outras classes?

Classe player possui o atributo Spellbook(classe que retorna uma lista com magias) e o atributo Backpack(classe que retorna uma outra lista que contém os itens,etc.) que são subclasses de uma lista.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name='', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._name = name
        self.spellbook = Spellbook(unit=self)
        self.base_damage = 0
        self.backpack = Backpack()
        self.level = 0
        self.stats = {'strength': 1, 'inteligence': 1}
        self.stats_points = 5
        self._up_experience = 0
        self._experience = 0
        self._max_health = 0
        self._health = 0
        self.max_mana = 0
        self._mana = 0
        self.base_mana_regeneration = 0
        self._mana_regeneration = 0
        self.potions = 4
        self._defense = 0
        self.base_defense = 0
        self.live_status = True
        self._gold = 0
        self._score = 0
        self.equipped_items = {
            'weapon': None,
            'shield': None,
            'head': None,
            'chest': None,
            'legs': None,
            'boots': None,
        }
        self._level_up()
```

Sempre quando vai serializar ele retorna esse erro:

```
TypeError: Object of type Heal is not JSON serializable
```

Nesse caso o erro está falando sobre a Spell(Heal) que tem no Spellbook, mas ele mostra o mesmo problema em relação aos itens.

Esta publicação aqui tem um cara que da um exemplo parecido com o que eu preciso, mas o código não funcionou comigo, fica em um loop infinito.

[Serializar Objeto para JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139710/serializar-objeto-para-json)

@Edit1

## Função que retorna os atributos que contém no player.

```
def save_data(player):
    data = {}
    for attr in player.__dict__:
        data[attr] = player.__dict__[attr]
    return data
```

## Função que salva o arquivo.

```
    def save_char(self, char):
        from game.units import save_data
        json.dump(save_data(char), open(f'saves/{char.name}.json', 'w'))
```

Comment: Como é que você manda serializar? Esse código tem que estar na pergunta. `json.dumps` que é o jeito normal de serializar coisas em JSON não funciona para instâncias de classe.

Comment: É exatamente o json.dumps que estou usando.

Comment: (sabe que você pode pressionar o botão `{}` para formatar o código aqui e preservar a identaçao, não é? Ou delimite o código com três \`\`\`  - mas arrume a identação - identação em Python não é só "bonitinho" - seus trechos de código acima são todos erros de sintaxe, e isso afasta pessos que possam querer responder)

Comment: Ainda não conheço bem os comandos da plataforma. Nem tinha reparado que estava fora da identação. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** A não ser que você precise passar os dados para um programa escrito em outra linguagem, ou editar manualmente como um arquivo texto, use `pickle` em vez de `json` para gravar estados de objetos.

Então o trecho *crucial* que estava faltando na versão original dessa pergunta é:

```py
def save_data(player):
    data = {}
    for attr in player.__dict__:
        data[attr] = player.__dict__[attr]
    return data
```

Sem isso parecia que você estava usando algo para serializar direto um objeto da classe player - é importante entender as informações que você precisa passar ao fazer uma pergunta - ninguém tem uma bola de cristal para saber o que você está querendo serializar.

Então - o que você passa acima para o json.dump é um dicionário - o serializador padrão do JSON sabe transformar dicionários em JSON. Mas não sabe transformar classes arbitrárias em JSON.

São dois caminhos a seguir para serializar todos os campos como JSON: ou você torna a função acima recursiva, e, a cada vez que encontrar um objeto que não seja uma lista ou um dicionário, chamar a própria função `save_data` passando o sub-objeto (claro que aí é melhor dar um nome mais apropriado para a função) - ou,
você customiza um serializador JSON que saiba entender classes comuns, e serializar o `__dict__` das instâncias. Esse segundo caminho exige que se crie uma subclasse de `json.JSONEncoder`.

Qualquer dos dois métodos acima tem uma desvantagem óbvia - para "rehidratar" os objetos, na hora de ler o JSON, você vai ter dicionários, não objetos da sua classe. Para recriar as classes corretamente é necessário criar uma função que vai ser passada como o parâmetro `object_hook` para o json.load, ou um decoder personalizado.

Por outro lado - se você não precisa que seus arquivos JSON sejam editáveis diretamente em um editor de textos - ou seja, seu jogo que vai sempre salvar e ler os arquivos, não há a menor necessidad de usar JSON para o que você quer -

Simplesmente salve os objetos do seu programa usando `pickle` em vez de JSON.  A diferença é que o pickle pode salvar e restaurar objetos arbitrários de Python, e não só strings, números, booleans, dicionários e listas, que é uma limitação do JSON.

Nesse caso você não precisa nem do código que está nessa `save_data` - simplesmente use o pickle da mesma forma que usa o módulo json, mas passando a sua instância diretamente:

```py
import pickle
...
pickle.dump(player, open(f'saves/{char.name}.pickle', 'wb'))
...
player  = pickle.load(open(open(f'saves/{char.name}.pickle', 'rb'))
```

(note que o pickle exige o arquivo aberto no modo binário, com a letra "b" após o "r" ou "w")